# Prestashop multishop function for multiple domain names

Tags: prestashop

If the backend is on let's say: http://testshop1.com,
How can I manage the webshop on: http://testshop2.com?

Answer (score 1):

Just install prestashop on both domains, 
copy images to frontoffice domain,
then make sure settings.inc.php is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)